# Дебаг qt приложения в ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt5

Столкнулся с такой весьма странной проблемой: при дебаге установке точки останова в методе, отвечающем за обработку ивентов (например mousPressEvent в графической сцене) ubuntu перестает откликаться. Тобишь невозможно взаимодействовать с экраном и даже терминал не вызвать, буд-то все зависло, но при этом запущенный в фоном режиме приложения продолжают работать.

Comment: Возможно, уже появилось full screen окно приложения, которое перекрывает окно IDE?

Comment: @cppquestions исключено, приложение не разворачивается на весь экран. К тому же в таком случае можно было бы вызвать терминал.

Comment: Вполне нормальная ситуация. Отладку стоит проводить исключительно удаленно посредством gdb server.